# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python, split, char, tuples, frequency

I'm trying to write some Python to take a cipher and split it into the letters and their frequency in the cipher. The issue I'm having is that I can get the code to print the frequency of the letters in the cipher, but I'm trying to get them individually so I can turn them into percentages to compare them against the common values found in a book, for example. E.g. I could compare the count of E's in my cipher to the average value of 12.7% in the English language. The issue I'm having is when I try and split the list of letters and their frequency, I get the AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'. Not sure what I can do so some help would be greatly appreciated. Here is my code:
import collections
import string

```
def freq():
    info = input("File Name")
    filehandle = open(info, "r")
    data = filehandle.read().upper()
    char_counter = collections.Counter(data)
    for char, count in char_counter.most_common():
        if char in string.ascii_uppercase:
            print(char, count)
            s = (char, count)
            frequency = s.split(",")
            for freq in frequency:
                print(freq)

freq()
```

This is the direct copy of the shell

```
File Nametest.rtf
E 59
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/Frequency.py", line 17, in <module>
    freq()
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/Frequency.py", line 13, in freq
    frequency = s.split(",")
 AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'
```

And here is what it was doing before:

```
File Nametest.rtf
E 59
A 43
T 39
R 37
O 29
F 25
P 25
S 23
L 23
I 22
N 19
D 18
B 17
C 15
H 14
M 12
G 9 
U 8
W 8
V 6
Y 4
X 3
K 3
```

Im looking for individual things of E 12% A 10% etc. or something similar if its possible.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should alter your code:

```
def freq():
    info = input("File Name")
    filehandle = open(info, "r")
    data = filehandle.read().upper()
    char_counter = collections.Counter(data)
    for char, count in char_counter.most_common():
        if char in string.ascii_uppercase:
            print(char, count)
            frequency = (char + str(count))
            for freq in frequency:
                print(freq)
```

The fixed rows:

```
    s = (char, count)
    frequency = s.split(",")
```

From so tiny information hard to tell what is the exact functionality of those rows, but the solution would be something like that.

Answer (score 2):

You are making s a tuple, tuples do not have split as the comma is not an actual part of the tuple it's a way of delimiting the different entries in code. Split only works for some types, i.e strings, and would only work if a comma was a part of the string/type instance.

I am not sure what you intended to get out of that part of your code, but you are telling it to create a tuple (char, count), then split that tuple at the comma (not possible, even if it did happen, you would have an array [char, count]) then for each of the values in that split tuple, print the value, which would print char, count.

Maybe go reexamine the way you went about this, you won't get any useful information from that split that you didn't already display in the prior print statement. If your intention was just the Letter and frequency, then you've already got that done, if you are trying to get proportions, add all the frequencies and then use each individual freq to get the proportion of the total it represents?